# Fast 3D matrix re-slicing

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a 3D matrix of size *(X, Y, Z)* which is stored in a data structure as *Z* matrices, each *X x Y* in size. I would like to re-slice these matrices to obtain *X* slices, each *Y x Z* in size. In other words, I want to reslice a 3D matrix stored as XY slices in the YZ plane. The use case is to reslice axial CT images into sagittal images. I am working inside a **browser environment.**

Here's an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ieee_pilot/articles/06/ttg2009061407/assets/img/article_1/fig_2/large.jpg](series)![enter image description here]

I have implemented the naive (iterative) solution in Python, which takes O(Y * Z) per slice. I haven't even bothered writing out the corresponding JavaScript implementation, because this approach is too slow by several orders of magnitude.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread

height, width, depth = 512, 512, 100

volume = np.zeros((height, width, depth))

s = 0

for filename in glob.iglob('./*.jpg'):
  volume[:,:,s] =  imread(filename)[...,0]/255.0
  s += 1

reslice = np.zeros((depth, height, width))

for s in xrange(0, width):
  current = np.zeros((depth, height))
  for i in xrange(0, height):
    for j in xrange(0, depth):
      current[j,i] = volume[i,s,j]
  reslice[:,:,s] = current
```

This algorithm seems to be amenable to parallelization. For example, in CUDA, one could load the 3D data into global memory, create one thread per pixel, then iterate for every slice in the new direction, and on each iteration ask the right pixels to fire in order to fill out the current slice. This would be a trivial kernel to write, and would be approximately O(1) per slice. However, I don't have access to CUDA in the browser.

Mapping from CUDA to WebCL is relatively straightforward, but WebCL is out of question given inexistent vendor support ATM. Therefore, I'm thinking WebGL is the ideal solution.

I'm not too sure how this would be done in the "WebGL" paradigm, but I'm sure it can be done, and I suspect it is fairly trivial as well. I can't seem to find where to start, however, and resources on doing general-purpose computations with OpenGL are extremely scarce. How would I go about using OpenGL to speed up reslicing of a 3D matrix inside the browser?

Comment: Two thing. First, I personally do not understand what you mean by re-slicing. Can you be more clear about that? A simple example would convey the idea I think. Second, can you show the code you have done and tried?

Comment: The use case is to re-slice sagittal images into axial CT images. Added the sample code.

Comment: You used a 512X512X100 matrix. 1) Is it the real size order of magnitude ? 2) Are the dimensions always power of two ? (so i guess height would be 128, not 100, in this case). 3) What is the depth required to store the pixel data in the array (8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit float, ...) ? 4) Are all matrix of the same size ? 5) can we assume the Browser is efficient (meaning : either Chrome or Firefox) ?

Comment: Thanks for your questions! 1) Yes, 2) No, 3) 8 bit unsigned (0-255), 4) No, 5) Yes.

Comment: Any reply for my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have necessarily to use webGL to be fast enough.

If you use a 3D array, JavaScript might be too slow but by using a ***flat*** array the time to reslice is in fact similar to the time it takes to create the array!

Another trick is to use a ***typed array*** to reduce memory usage and improve performances (Uint8Array).

I created a small class to handle such a flat array and to slice it.

I think the most relevant thing you want is in fact to get a ***view***, either on (x, y) axes or (y, z) axes.

Since Array creation is very slow, you want to build the view on place within a fixed buffer. And since you want also a sliced view, you have to create a buffer and method also for the sliced view. 
It's fast: creating a view for your 512X512x100 example take ***less than 5 ms!***
(So in fact, the putImageData you'll have to do afterward will quite take more time! )

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/n38mwh95/1/

Here's the class handling the data, you'll have to change the constructor so it accepts the real raw data:

```
function Array3D(xSize, ySize, zSize) {
    this.xSize = xSize;
    this.ySize = ySize;
    this.zSize = zSize;
    var xyMultiplier = xSize * ySize;

    this.array = new Uint8Array(xSize * ySize * zSize);

    this.view = new Uint8Array(xSize * ySize);

    this.slicedView = new Uint8Array(ySize * zSize);

    this.valueAt = function (x, y, z) {
        return this.array[x + xSize * (y + z * ySize)];
    };

    this.setValueAt = function (x, y, z, val) {
        return this.array[x + xSize * (y + z * ySize)] = val;
    };

    this.buildView = function (z) {
        var src = this.array;
        var view = this.view;
        for (var x = 0; x < xSize; x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < ySize; y++) {
                view[x + xSize * y] = src[x + xSize * (y + z * ySize)];
            }
        }
        return view;
    };

    this.buildSlicedView = function (x) {
        var src = this.array;
        var sView = this.slicedView;
        for (var y = 0; y < ySize; y++) {
            for (var z = 0; z < zSize; z++) {
                sView[y + ySize * z] = src[x + xSize * (y + z * ySize)];
            }
        }
        return sView;
    };
}
```

In use:

```
var xSize = 512;
var ySize = 512;
var zSize = 100;

var t1, t2;

t1 = performance.now();
var testArray = new Array3D(xSize, ySize, zSize);
t2 = performance.now();
console.log('created in :' + (t2 - t1));

t1 = performance.now();
var resliced = testArray.buildView(10);
t2 = performance.now();

console.log('building view in :' + (t2 - t1));

var x = 80;
t1 = performance.now();
var resliced = testArray.buildSlicedView(x);
t2 = performance.now();

console.log('building sliced view in :' + (t2 - t1));
```

Results:

```
created in :33.92199998779688 (index):73
building view in :2.7559999871300533 (index):79
building sliced view in :5.726000003051013
```

At the end of the code I also added some code to render the view.

Don't forget to cache the canvas imageData: create it only once then re-use it for best performance.

You could easily have a real-time rendering in fact.